# Prevent PHP from reading own source files

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, php

For simplicity consider the following example: We have a file `secret.php` that runs our back end code and it includes a file `custom.php` somewhere a long the line. Obviously the apache-user must be able to read both files to work, but can you prevent using something like `file_get_contents('secret.php')` to get the source code?

We do have some control over `custom.php` before it is loaded, so it's possible to use a coding solution with white and/or blacklist on php functions, but that adds a major layer of complexity I'd rather not use.

Can you setup apache / php / ubuntu in a way that allows execution of php files but not reading them?

Answer (score 2):

While there are lots of ways to restrict file access via the operating system, none of these can differentiate between PHP scripts run by the same executable process, by the same user, in the same context, on the same host.

However you can enforce constraints within PHP itself via open_basedir - this can be set on a per path basis (or via other criteria) in the webserver config. e.g.

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
        php_admin_value open_basedir "/usr/share/php"
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/html/privileged_scripts>
        php_admin_value open_basedir "/usr/share/php:/usr/share/restricted"
</Directory>
```

However if an attacker can get their code running on your webserver, this is not going to provide much protection.

As implemented above, this is applied to the PHP script mapped directly to the URL - scripts it subsequently includes inherit this value.

Comment: Thank you for the open_basedir suggestion. This might be enough for our goal and we'll definitely set up a test case to see if we can get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

> Obviously the apache-user must be able to read both files to work, but can you prevent using something like file_get_contents('secret.php') to get the source code?

No. On UNIX-alike systems (like your Ubuntu Linux), file access permissions are handed out on a process-basis. So, if the process needs to be able to read a file, you will have to grant the process the ability to read it – for any purpose.

You *can* do much more advanced things using seccomp whilst modifying your PHP source code (and possibly even the PHP interpreter) to disable reading the file after a certain point in time, but that's going to be cooperative.

If you need a security boundary between secret.php and custom.php, you should probably at least separate their processes – and make them communicate, e.g. via a domain socket, or POSIX shared memory, or actual network sockets, or simply through pipes. Mind you, PHP has no great representation for "code running in other process working on the same data structures as this process", much less for nicely represented RPC, so this will all incur a significant serialization/deserialization overhead. 
You might want to consider migrating away from PHP if you can't trust code that you run (which, by the way, is the nr.1 reason for wordpress instances getting hijacked: untrustworthy code run in themes that *should* only modify the HTML output but *do* sinister things).

Comment: erm, no. Unix permissions are based on users/groups not processes. MAC does allow for behaviours based on the process, but in this scenario its still the same process so that doesn't help.

Comment: @symcbean I didn't say "based on", I intentionally chose the wording "handed out": the thing that decides whether a `read()` can be done is the process'es privileges. These are *not purely* based on the effective User/group of that process (as in Unix in the 70s), but you need to take Linux capabilites, namespaces, and things like compsec into account! But yeah, same process, no help. As said, a bit in the spirit of BSD `pledge` and similar mechanisms, your process can voluntarily lose privileges (and if its just by setting a different effective UID; but that would require root to begin with).

Comment: Thanks for the input. This is in no way intended to be foul proof, but more a discouragement for freelancers working on our system from downloading the core software. They are bound by law with an NDA, but it doesn't hurt to have something extra in place.

Comment: @HugoDelsing I'd strongly recommend stopping to hope that happens. The source code they are not supposed to download is quite probably still there in the process that runs their code. They can get it. If you can't trust your freelancers, don't let them run their code. And especially don't let them run their code in your process. And especially don't let them run their code in your PHP process.

Comment: @HugoDelsing You just literally gave us four big red flags regarding your system's architectural security: untrustworthy code in non-sandbox environment, untrustworthy code in same process, attempt to ignore trust problem with superficial non-fixes, and thinking plugging PHP could stop them. It is time for a software re-design, to be honest! Isolate the non-trustworthy code to a VM, to a container, or at the very least to its own process. Define interfaces for your code with which the freelancer code can interact – and don't implement a "read my code" interface. Implement harsh restrictions…

Comment: … on the untrustworthy code-running instances. What you're trying to do here is like asking about which mop to bring to a dam breach; the answer is none, you need something that can stop flood waters, not a mop up a puddle.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Your making many assumptions without knowing most details. The only person you can trust is yourself, but if you need to expand your business you need more developers. It doesn't matter how you call them; employee; freelancer; interim; whatever; they will be able to access source code. You prevent them from sharing it with an NDA. One extra step to prevent them from direct access to some parts of the code isn't a security flaw. It's like a padlock. You don't stop malicious intent but you do prevent a curious bystander.

Comment: @MarcusMüller and there is nothing in my question about a sandbox environment or not. There is, but a sandbox environment also needs all parts of the code to run. And whether their code ends up in production isn't any part of this question either. It won't, it will be checked. But that doesn't stop them from taking a peak before releasing the final code for testing. And obviously having a separated process is best, but who would develop the core that enables this? Right, other developers.

Comment: yes, but these other developers would be the ones that you trust as much as the ones currently developing your core that these freelancers you don't trust aren't supposed to read. All in all, while you're right, I was making a security problem out of a confidentiality problem, it still sounds like you'd massively benefit from a clearer separation of concerns, even, and especially, on a legal basis: For example, if one of the developers who you trust less copies some AGPL code into their code. Suddenly, a competitor comes on and says, "hey, that whole system is AGPL, you gave me access to the

Comment: part the lesser-trusted freelancer wrote, so now I'm entitled to the full source code of your system!" They'd be right. If you can't trust people to not read your source code, you cannot trust them to not introduce funky code, and then you need to introduce clean separation. Just a thing to think about. Personally, if you can't give your code to your freelancers, freely, and in full,, your code must either be very very bad, or you really really shouldn't be contracting with these freelancers. That's my 2ct as FOSS maintainer *and* Freelancer.